# how can I do ip forwarding with one NIC?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy, ip, nic

I have two computers and each has one NIC . is it possible to forward IP through one NIC? or I need at least 2 NIC in one of my computers?

EDITE:

I need ip forwarding in my local zone. for example computer A with ip 192.168.1.2 and computer B with ip 192.168.1.3. I need to forward the packets of computer B  through computer A. each of computers has one NIC

Comment: IP forwarding also known as Internet routing is a process used to determine which path a packet or datagram can be sent. The process uses routing information to make decisions and is designed to send a packet over multiple networks. Generally, networks are separated from each other by routers.

Comment: @David I need ip forwarding in my local zone. for example computer A with ip 192.168.1.2 and computer B with ip 192.168.1.3. I need to forward my computer B packets through computer A. each of computers has one NIC.

Comment: Which requires a router.

Comment: You can review this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network) It is about IP forwarding within the same LAN with `iptables`.